# Is the following function upper semi-continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

### Definition

Let $f$ be defined on $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\mathbf{x}_0$ be a limit point of $E$ which lies in $E$.

Then $f$ is said to be usc (upper semiconitnuous) at $\mathbf{x}_0$ if
$$\limsup_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{x}_0;~\mathbf{x}\in{}E} f(\mathbf{x}) \le f(\mathbf{x}_0)$$

---

There is a theorem:

If $f(\mathbf{x}_0) = +\infty$, then $f$ is automatically usc at $\mathbf{x}_0$.

---

However I want to know that the following:

Although $f$ is usc at $\mathbf{x}_0$, can $f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ be $-\infty$?

---

For example, Let \begin{equation} f(x)= \cases{-\frac{1}{x^2} & if $x\ne0$\\ -\infty & if $x=0$} \end{equation}
Then, does the following statement hold?

$$\limsup_{x\to0} f(x) \le f(0)$$

---

For your information, the motivation of this question is from proving that "if $f$ and $g$ are usc at $x_0$, then $f+g$ is usc at $x_0$".

Solution said that "if one is $+\infty$ and the other is $-\infty$, then it's not clear what to make of $f(x_0)+g(x_0)$, so we'll ignore that case."

However I do not understand why it can be ignored.

Comment: Yes, your $f$ is usc at $0$. We _cannot_ ignore that case; if functions taking the values $\pm\infty$ are allowed, as they evidently are, then the statement being proved is not quite true.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you very much. I understood!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function you provide is usc at $0$. This is simply because for any $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\to 0$, we have
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = -\infty
$$
and therefore $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(0)=-\infty$.

When $f(x_0)=\infty$ and $g(x_0)=-\infty$, we can (and must) ignore the case $f(x_0)+g(x_0)$ because $f(x_0)+g(x_0)=\infty-\infty$ which is undefined.

Comment: Why must it be ignored? I believe that if at lease one case is ignored, the theorem doesn't hold anymore. That is, I think the theorem "if $f$ and $g $ are usc at $x_0$, then so is $f+g$." should be considered as being wrong, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, the theorem is only correct if constrained to additions which are defined. $\infty - \infty$ is not defined.